# How do I match a text which can contain - or an underscore using regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl

I want the username to be any characters with `_` or `-` in it but this in Perl is not working, why is it?

```
if ("kunjaaN-" =~ /^[a-zA-Z-_]{1,7}$/)
{ print "equal" ; }
```

Comment: Dude, first you asked what an underscore does in a regexp, now you're asking why you can't match an underscore when you didn't include it in the pattern??!

Comment: Wow The PERL community in stackoverflow are pretty hostile to newbies...anyway I think the problem was the {1,7} and not the _ .

Comment: @kunjaan: only some.  try to ignore it.

Comment: No, not hostile to newbies. You don't look like you try very hard to solve your own problems, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not working because `kunjaaN-` is eight characters, and you're limiting yourself to 1..7

For a username, why not increase the limit to something decent?

Also, if you want `_` included you need to include that in your character class.

Try this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z_-]{1,16}\z
```

**Note:**
Inside character classes, the `-` character can have special meaning. For example, `[a-z]` means 'the range of characters starting with `a` and ending in `z`', whilst `[az-]` means 'either `a` or `z` or `-`'.

To make a `-` non-special you can place it at the start or end of a class, or escape it with a backslash. `[a\-z]` will match `a` or `z` or `-`.
Escaping is generally preferred since it avoids accidents if extra characters are inadvertently added to the end of the class.

Comment: Heh, we all do things like this from time to time. :)

Comment: Yes, but not all of us have asked what the underscore does in a regular expression ;-)

Comment: You make the change but don't point it out, about the problems with the question's character class. The original version didn't include match on -. The reason for this is that - is treated as a range operator unless it is the frist or last character.

Comment: EmFi, pay attention to edit times - the question was modified after I answered. Since the question has now changed, I'll go add information about when `-` is special or not.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to allow a possible newline at the end of your string, use the \z end of string anchor instead of the $ anchor:

```
 /^[a-z_-]{1,8}\z/i
```